# UISearchController NSFetchResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8, uisearchcontroller

I'm getting this error:

> CoreData: error: Serious application error. An exception was caught
>   from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to
>   -controllerDidChangeContent:. attempt to delete row 5 from section 0 which only contains 1 rows before the update with userInfo (null) If I
>   edit first or second not last everything is working.

I have a tableview and UISearchController and when I touch on row from tableview it send me in another vc where I can edit my diary.
Everything is working fine except when I search something and if the result is last entry from my TableView when I try to edit and save it gives me the error I wrote above.

```
@implementation PlumbListTableViewController


-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
  [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
 }

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];

   self.searchController =[[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:nil];

    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO;
    self.searchController.searchBar.frame = CGRectMake(self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.x, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.origin.y, self.searchController.searchBar.frame.size.width, 44.0);

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
   self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self;

     self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO;
    [self showTotalSum];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)searchBar{
[self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)searchForText:(NSString *)searchText
{
    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AddEntry"];
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];
    if (self.searchController.searchBar.text.length == 0) {
         NSError *error = nil;
        self.filteredList = [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    } else {

    if (coreDataStack.managedObjectContext) {

   NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"titluPlumb contains[c] %@", searchText];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
          NSError *error = nil;
        self.filteredList = [coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    }
    }
}



- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
    NSString *searchString = searchController.searchBar.text;

    [self searchForText:searchString ];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:(NSInteger)selectedScope
{
    [self updateSearchResultsForSearchController:self.searchController];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {


    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"edit"]) {
        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        UINavigationController *navigationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        PlumbAddViewController *entryViewController = (PlumbAddViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

        if (self.searchController.active) {
            entryViewController.entry = [self.filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        } else {
        entryViewController.entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        }
   }
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    if (self.searchController.active)
    {
           return [self.filteredList count];
      }
    else
    {
        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];
   }

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ConfigureCellPlumb *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    AddEntry *entry = nil;

    if (self.searchController.active){

        entry = [self.filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    } else {

           entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    }

    cell.titluView.text = entry.titluPlumb;
    cell.descriereView.text = entry.bodyPlumb;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:entry.date];
    cell.dataLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    if (entry.imageDataPlumb) {
        cell.imagineView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.imageDataPlumb];
    } else {
        cell.imagineView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_noimage"];
    }

    return cell;

}


- (NSFetchRequest *)entryListFetchRequest {
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AddEntry"];

    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];

    return fetchRequest;
}

- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    AddEntry *entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CoreDataStack *coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    [[coreDataStack managedObjectContext] deleteObject:entry];
    [coreDataStack saveContext];
}



- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id<NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo>)sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch (type) {
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
            break;
        }

}

- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {

    [self.tableView endUpdates];

}

@end
```

UPDATE:

```
- (NSFetchRequest *)entryListFetchRequest {
    self.searchFetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AddEntry"];

    self.searchFetchRequest.sortDescriptors = @[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO]];





    return self.searchFetchRequest;
}


- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    self.coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];
    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    if (self.searchController.searchBar.text.length != 0) {
        NSString *searchText = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"titluPlumb contains[c] %@", searchText];
        [self.searchFetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

             NSError *error = nil;
        self.filteredList = [self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:self.searchFetchRequest error:&error];
    }


return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

UPDATE 2

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    self.coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

    if (self.searchController.searchBar.text.length !=0) {
       NSString *searchText = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"titluPlumb contains[c] %@", searchText];
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    }

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
```

self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
            [self.tableView reloadData];

```
    }
}
```

UPDATE 3

```
#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.

    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

        id <NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo> sectionInfo = [self.fetchedResultsController sections][section];
        return [sectionInfo numberOfObjects];


}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ConfigureCellPlumb *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    AddEntry *entry = nil;

           entry = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];


    cell.titluView.text = entry.titluPlumb;
    cell.descriereView.text = entry.bodyPlumb;

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:entry.date];
    cell.dataLabel.text = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];

    if (entry.imageDataPlumb) {
        cell.imagineView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:entry.imageDataPlumb];
    } else {
        cell.imagineView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icn_noimage"];
    }

    return cell;

}
```

UPDATE 4

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    self.coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
   self.searchFetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

    if (self.searchController.searchBar.text.length !=0) {
       NSString *searchText = self.searchController.searchBar.text;
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"titluPlumb contains[c] %@", searchText];
        self.searchFetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:self.searchFetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;


    return [_fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects];
}


- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController
{
 self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [self.tableView reloadData];


     NSLog(@"%@", self.searchFetchRequest.predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your table view is driven by 2 sources at th same time (in this scenario) because you aren't fully turning the FRC off while searching. So, you do your search and make your edit, the FRC sees this and tries to update the table, but - the table isn't currently showing FRC rows - so sometimes it will fail.

Either use the FRC to do the search by changing the predicate on the fetch request, or destroy the FRC while you're searching and recreate it when you're done.

---

So, change your FRC method to:

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {
    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }
    self.coreDataStack = [CoreDataStack defaultStack];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [self entryListFetchRequest];

    if (self.searchController.searchBar.text.length != 0) {
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"titluPlumb contains[c] %@", searchText];
        fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
    }

    _fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.coreDataStack.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:@"sectionName" cacheName:nil];
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;
}
```

and whenever you start a search / change search text / end a search do:

```
self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74733/discussion-on-answer-by-wain-uisearchcontroller-nsfetchresultscontroller).

Comment: Dear Wain thanks for all, is not working when I delete section name, in my tableView is showing nothing... I'm sorry that you spend all day for me.... Thanks!!!